# strange error with cin.getline

Tags: file, text

The task requirement is to request for the number of lines of output in the text file, and then request for the input line by line. Each line contains 2 numbers side by side. A sample file would be:

4
75 65
80 75
90 85
55 65

I have tried writing the code, however, there seems to be one line of input that is missing. could you guys please help me out? Much appreciated!!

int main()
{

```
char file_name[81];
char buffer[81];
int lines;

cout << "input file name: ";
cin.getline(file_name,81);

cout << "input number of lines: ";
cin >> lines;

ofstream out_file(file_name);
if (!out_file)
{
    cout << "\nerror, file already exists. choose another file name.";
    return 0;
}

while (lines != 0)
{
    cout << "enter first number: "; cin.getline(buffer, 81);
    out_file << buffer << "\t";

    cout << "\nenter second number: "; cin.getline(buffer ,81);
    out_file << buffer << endl;

    lines--;

}


out_file.close();

cout << "\nprogram terminated";

cout << endl; return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
cout << "input number of lines: ";
cin >> lines;
```

add

```
cin.ignore(1);
```

Comment: When you input the number of lines, it reads the integer and the enter key. Without the ignore, the enter sequence is carried over to the next getline.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, but thanks a zillion! It worked.